# How to setup a platform with TPM?

Tags: security, tpm

I am trying to learn about TPMs. I would like a machine with a TPM. I understand that this is a chip on the motherboard? Is a TPM something that you can install or is it something that comes soldered on to the motherboard? How do I find a platform or just motherboard with a TPM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand that this is a chip on the motherboard?

Usually

> Is a TPM something that you can install or is it something that comes soldered on to the motherboard?

Some systems have the TPM as an add-in "card" that connects via a LPC bus.

> How do I find a platform or just motherboard with a TPM?

Most business-grade PCs have TPM chips already. Some "enthusiast" motherboards do as well. Most business-grade servers have TPM add-in cards available.